# How to generate mymodule.contract.h with vsdconfigtool?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I want to write a native custom visualizer for visual studio debugger. I started from scratch and I am following this example

https://github.com/microsoft/ConcordExtensibilitySamples/tree/main/CppCustomVisualizer/dll

But I am stuck generating the equivalent for "CppCustomVisualizer.Contract.h".

It is required to compile CppCustomVisualizer.dll. I read that vsdconfigtool generates this file, however when I run "vsdconfigtool mymodule.vsdconfigxml mymodule.vsdconfig" it says an input dll is required

"ERROR: No input dlls were specified on the command line. At least one .dll file is required to output a .vsdconfig file."

What is this input DLL?

Comment: Minxin Yu. From Cambridge dictionary. Analog: something that is similar to or can be used instead of something else:

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there are two syntax, one for generating the header file and another for generating the vsdconfig file, I was mistakenly trying to generate both header and vsdconfig file in the same step. This is the syntax:

```
synax: VsdConfigTool <input_config> <input_dll> <ouput_config>
       -or-
       VsdConfigTool <input_config> <output_header>
```

mymodule.contract.h

If I run `vsdconfigtool mymodule.vsdconfigxml mymodule.contract.h` it generates the header file mymodule.contract.h.

Then, to generate the mymodule.vsdconfig, after having compiled mymodule.dll, `vsdconfigtool mymodule.vsdconfigxml mymodule.dll mymodule.vsdconfig`.